Go to source on Texstudio
I used TexStudio and I tried many ways to enable the "Go to source" function but it seems like my version does not support this. These are some ways that I tried:

Right click.
Ctrl + Right click.
Check out the pdfview

Can some one help me out?

Is synctex enabled in your call to LaTeX? (in the editor config)

Ctrl + Left click

Yes i enable synctex, it is -synctex=1 right?

Ctrl + Left click does not work though

@HưngTrần Is there a .synctex.gz file in the same folder as your .tex file?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz oh yes there is

@HưngTrần That's good. Which version of texstudio do you use? Do you use the internal pdf viewer or an external one?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i believe I am using internal pdf viewer

@HưngTrần If you right click in the pdf, do you see "Go to Source" as first option in the menu?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I do not. There are some sorts of option like Zoom in, Zoom out, grayscale, etc

@HưngTrần Which version of texstudio do you have?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It's 4.8.0

That sounds more or less up-to-date and should support synctex. Can you post a screenshot so we can confirm that you are using the internal viewer?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i added the picture

looks good. Can you check if there are any error in the .log file? Can you test with a different document?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Like what error? And no, the other files of mine meet the same error

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Even when I change the file name, it still does not work

An image of the commands pane would be better. Has "got o source" ever worked on your system? Are there any non-ascii chars in the path to your file?
